# Why GCC long long int can't do 1<<48 but gets an overflow warning

Tags: c, integer-overflow, gcc-warning

```
{
    unsigned long long two16, two48 ;
    two16 = 65536;
    two48 = two16 * two16 * two16 ; 
    printf("2^48=%llX \n",two48 );
    two48 = 1<<48 ;
    printf("Shifted 1<<48=%llX \n",two48);
    return 0 ;
}
```

When compiled on a 64 bit machine, with a word size of 8, the above gives a warning the two=1<<48 will overflow
left shift count >= width of type.

The output of the program is:

```
    2^48=1000000000000  
    Shifted 1<<48=0
```

What is going on? Why can I not shift a 64bit quantity 48 bits?

Comment: An expression gets the type of the operands used by that expression, _not_ some type used in a different (sub)expression. `1` is of type `int` so that's what the shift is executed on. Left-shifting such a signed int beyond 31 bits is undefined behavior. _Never type `1<< ...` in a C program_! It is never correct. It should always be `1U`, `1UL` etc or something cast to an unsigned type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> why can I not shift a 64bit quantity 48 bits?

You are *not* shifting a 64-bit integer by 48. You are shifting a 32-bit integer (`1`) by 48, and assigning the (overflown) result to a 64-bit integer. Try this instead:

```
two48 = 1ULL << 48;
```

or this:

```
two48 = 1;
two48 = two48 << 48;
```